# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, exception, illegalstateexception

excuse me, I created a CRUD project using Kotlin, and I'm having a problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL7Rv.png) "Exceptions in the main" java thread **"java.lang.IllegalStateException:"**
how do I deal with Excpetion as above what am I doing?

Comment: That exception message alone is simply not enough to determine the problem. We can't help you without seeing the relevant code. 1. Please post the relevant code. 2. Please don't post screenshots of text. 3. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The screenshot you posted contains a stacktrace (the red text). There is a link in it to your `main` function, which will bring you to the line where the error occurred. This is a good starting point for finding the problem. If you don't find the problem on your own, you can post the stacktrace here and the snippet of code that triggered the exception, explaining which line exactly is responsible. WIthout this, it's impossible to help you

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`error()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/error.html) function in your `else` branch (probably in a `when` statement).
This function in Kotlin is defined as throwing `IllegalStateException`:

> `fun error(message: Any): Nothing`
>
> Throws an IllegalStateException with the given message.

This is the intended behaviour of that function.
If you're asking this question, I guess that it is not the behaviour you intended.

Throwing exceptions is most likely not what you want for user errors in a CLI application. Instead you can use the `stderr` stream to write the error message to the console without crashing the program:

```kotlin
System.err.println("the error message")
```